# How can I override Cordova's audioCapture interface in iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap/Cordova project that utilizes the `org.apache.cordova.media-capture` plugin to capture audio (`capture.captureAudio`).

iOS has a listed "quirk" that it doesn't have a native audio capturing graphical interface. PhoneGap/Cordova automatically provides the following GUI:

[image: PhoneGap/Cordova Default iOS Audio Capturing GUI]

Can this be overridden/edited somehow? I'm talking more about *theming* (changing the background/image, button styles etc) the interface than re-coding whole screen. I don't need more functionalities to be added on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the images available on the bundle
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/tree/master/src/ios/CDVCapture.bundle

You can try to download the plugin, replace the images with others of your own and add the plugin locally.

Another option might be to create your own plugin using the same code but creating your own bundle for images (changing the code where necessary)

Comment: Yup, this works. Although, for some reason, modifications to the resources are not reflected when using [Phonegap testing app](http://phonegap.com/app/). If I run the app in the emulator, the resources are changed.

Comment: That's because phonegap app has the original plugin installed. As the app is in github, you can change the resources there too and create your own version of the app https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer